# Need to copy a specific text generated on page to a string in PHP

Tags: php

I made a PHP script which is generating result "https://secure.nmi.com/api/v2/three-step/44505010" 
44505010 is a number that changes every time. I need to create a $reference string which I can assign that dynamic number to $reference.

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me out?

```
$reference = getStr($page, 'https://secure.nmi.com/api/v2/three-step/','');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourUrl = 'https://secure.nmi.com/api/v2/three-step/44505010';    
$reference = (int) explode('/', $yourUrl)[6];
```

This assumes the general URL format does not change.

Comment: What do I assign into $yourUrl? The curl_opt of $page is generating that link everytime with a different number at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function getUrlPart($url = '') {

    $urlarr = parse_url($url);
    $split = explode('/', $urlarr['path']);
    $c = 1;

    while($split[count($split)-$c] == ''){
        $c++;
    }

    return var_export($split[count($split)-$c], true);

}

$url = 'https://secure.nmi.com/api/v2/three-step/44505010//';

echo getUrlPart($url);
```

In this method you can get the route name at any depth, even with query parameters at the end.

Comment: How can I assign the url into $urlarr ? It is being generated by the code and that number changes everytime.

Comment: You said in the question that "I made a PHP script which is generating result". Just return 
 this result and put it in a variable like $url.